# MongoDB 3.4 : Insert a keyword in between in existing field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-3.4

I have a collection "school" having a field name "student", student is already created field
and now I want to add a keyword lets says I want to split the student name and add a hypen "-" before kumar only if name has kumar in it. And then concat all of them and store in same field How should I do it?

I tried using aggregate pipeline and is working but remaining records which did not got updated are getting removed because of $out.

I tried using $replaceOne inside $set under updateMany, but $replaceOne is not getting recognized.

Comment: Try placing your aggregation pipeline (without `$out`) as the second argument to the `update` command. See [here in the documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-with-aggregation-pipeline)

Comment: And I see, update takes aggregation pipeline after 4.2 verision in documentation but I tried making chnages to the command to make it work then it says stackoverflow error, can I please have a solution using map or something

Comment: Oh I missed the `3.4` constraint. If you're okay to rewrite the whole collection then I definitely think there's a solution here. Can you create and share a mongoplayground link with some sample documents and the aggregation pipeline that you tried? _Separately it's worth saying that you should think about upgrading. Version 3.4 is almost 7 years old, and even the 'new' `4.2` version required to use aggregation pipelines in `update` commands is old enough that it is no longer supported..._

Comment: I'm afraid Upgrading to new version is not possible not in my hands, its not for personal project. https://mongoplayground.net/p/_S0vvT6VTGb.  we have almost 40k records to be updated.

Comment: If you are going to go with the `$out` approach then think you want something closer to [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8nZlldn_Ajc). One main point is to get rid of the `$match` since you're going to have to rewrite the whole collection. Instead we move that conditional logic into the `$addFields`. You may also encounter some casing issues, but that should point you in a direction.

Comment: I can not go with $out, this is not for a testing database, I can not rewrite the collection. can not we use updatemany , or use $map or something else which can update the field and not rewriting teh collection

Comment: Well `$map` is an aggregation operator, so since you are on an old version that doesn't support updates with aggregation pipelines usage of it is out. The general problem is that you need to access and conditionally modify the existing field which does not have good support for until later versions. Perhaps your best option is to retrieve all 40k relevant records to the client and issue a bulk write back with the modifications.