# Mongo DB 3.4 : How to update a field by concatinating it with a keyword by passing current value to javascript function instead of using $concat

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-3.4

What should I pass here in the updateName() method argument which holds data of existing "name" field received from db? can it be one?

```
    var updateName = function(nameValue) {

  return nameValue+"123"
};
db.test.updateOne({_id: ObjectId("123")},
{$set:{ name: updateName()}})
```

Comment: This question looks like it is related to [your earlier one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77315761/mongodb-3-4-insert-a-keyword-in-between-in-existing-field). Keep in mind that your `updateName()` function is going to execute and resolve client side _before_ it is sent to the server. So you would instead need to change your code to `find()` the document first and then send the associated value from that document to the function.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I was trying to find another easy solution for my problem, Thanks

Comment: Yeah this seems like the approach you might have to take, which is what I was suggesting at the end of [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77315761/mongodb-3-4-insert-a-keyword-in-between-in-existing-field#comment136305389_77315761). I would highly recommend using bulk writes to send the updates back instead of doing them one at a time. Otherwise the network latency will result in the full set of operations taking a very long time. See [here in the documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/)